# why spring boot does not load application yml when packaged (With gradle)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

Not found anything interesting so far, so here am I, asking a question.

I got a spring boot application, that runs fine. Problem is : custom configuration !
I want it to run on port 8081 (and not default port 8080). So I added the application.yml in the src/main/resources directory, packaged it... And it run on port 8080
When I run the @SpringBootApplication class from intellij, it does run on port 8081 (I just added the application.yml file.) So why ?

It's a gradle multi module project. T added the application.yml file into the module that is actually packaged into a jar file. It is packaged using tha gradle shadow plugin, and does contain the application.yml file at the root of the jar file.

The application.yml is like this :

```
server:
    port: 8081
```

I don't really know which information you'll need, so feel free to ask !

Any idea is welcome.

**EDIT 1 :**
"Stacktrace" when I start the server :

```
java -jar serverApp.jar 

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                        

août 29, 2020 5:50:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
août 29, 2020 5:50:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFOS: Starting service [Tomcat]
août 29, 2020 5:50:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFOS: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
août 29, 2020 5:50:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
août 29, 2020 5:50:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

Comment: Please share you stacktrace and code

Comment: @SkillsIndexOutOfBounds which part of the code ?

Comment: This shouldn't be the full trace. Add full one please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Shadow Plugin is not the right thing to use with Spring Boot according to [this](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/296#issuecomment-300980079) comment:

> the boot framework has it's own gradle plugin and method for packaging ditributable jar files. I dont' think I would combine shadow and the boot plugin in the same project. They will collide.

and also [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-use-the-gradle-shadow-plugin-to-merge-spring-handlers-and-spring-schemas-files-of-multiple-spring-jar-dependencies/6713/3).

Comment: Seems you was right. Took me a while, got issues to upgrade gradle, not totally clear in my heads, not sure if totally upgraded, but at least the wrapper is, project compiling, no more shadow war but gradle plugin, and that works fine :)
Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the actual code, I can recommend 2 things to try.

1- Have you missed to use the argument in main method-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
}
```

2- Try to start the springboot server with arguments-

```
java -jar -Dserver.port=8081 ServerApplication.jar
```

Comment: 1- It does looks like this, with args, etc.

2 - Tried, doesn't even work.... I do really want it in a property / yml file, but even on a command line it does not work...

Comment: My bad, option 2 worked, my terminal hided some char, so I had -Dservrvrer.port --'  I still prefer it on a file, any ideas ?

Comment: @Mlem , to fix it in the file you have to share your code as well, I am sure it must be some minor mistake you are doing.
If option 2 solves your query, please approve/upvote the answer.

Comment: which part of the code you need ? I have no code related to this property
Pretty sure it's minor too, I think i'll feel stupid when I will find it, but can't see it atm....

Comment: Just project scaffolding like the main class, build grdle, application.yaml.
Pust it to your github repo , and share the link.